# Не приходят письма с сайта

Tags: email, centos, smtp

На сайте идет отправка писем через smtp (регистрация и активация юзера) .

`dmark, dkim, ptr` - все настроено и во всех чекерах проблем не выдает. 
При отправке почты на mail, google, yandex - почта приходит через раз, а иногда в спам улетает .

В данном случае больше всего интересно, почему иногда не доходят до адреса сообщения.

Где искать проблему ? Может ip где-то в черном списке, может текст самих сообщений изменить ?

Comment: @Serkis Allahverdian Вы проверяли отправку? Ставили логгирование? Они точно все отправляются?

Comment: Читайте заголовки полученного письма в этих самых mail, google, yandex — там обычно имеются результаты их собственных проверок

Comment: @Denis640Kb уточните, какое именно логгинирование и как включить

Comment: @andreymal так письма не приходят, что читать-то ?

Comment: открыл лог и почистил . 
Далее, выполняю на сайте регистрацию юзера. Письмо не приходит и в логе ничего не обновляется.

Через пару попыток повторной регистрации - письмо пришло и лог обновился

Comment: вроде как решилась проблема заменой 25 порта на 465. Но все равно непонятно, почему сообщения через раз приходили